# How to ENABLE the Advance option in Report Server Web Service URLs (Reporting Service Configuration Manager)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

To start with, I am completely new to SSRS reporting. Please excuse me if I miss any basic details here. I am trying to create a reporting service.I want to work on the Advance option in Web Service Url, but it's disabled. How can I enable the Advance option here? To have a clear picture, I am adding the images below.

[image]

Kindly help. Any leads or solution will be appreciated. :) Thank You

Comment: Just click on "apply" and it will configure the Web Service URL

Answer (score 0):

If you read the message above carefully it says "simply press the Apply button".

Once you do this it will apply the defaults, after which the Advanced button will be enabled, the URL will become a click-able hyperlink.

[image: Message]

Comment: Note added by [@brady-jesson](/users/17245578): "_you do have to navigate off the particular section you're looking at and then come back to it for the Advanced button to become active._"